# adding files to all platforms of a cocos2d-x project

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

This is a very basic question, but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere.

I just got Cocos 2Dx 3.3, made a new project and built the HelloWorld scene that was generated.

It generated projects for all platforms, but I am currently compiling and running the Mac project using XCode.

I can easily add new files using XCode, but of course it only adds it to my XCode Project. I would have expected a way to automatically modify all projects at once to add files or change compiler settings. I saw that there is a CMake file, probably used for command line compilation, but I cannot find a way to use that to regenerate the projects for all platforms.

Is it possible to automatically add a file to all platforms? Maybe it is possible to modify the template directory os Cocos and use the `cocos new` command line to recreate the project from scratch?

Or is it better to do all that manually?

Comment: Being able to add files once to a cross-platform build system like CMake and have it generate the per-platform build systems and IDE projects is not at all an unreasonable expectation. Have you had any luck in getting this to work in the intervening years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an automation would imply parsing of a project file, finding list of relevant files and then changing all the dozen of project files. Which is hell of the work.

Even if it was implemented, how would this implementation decide which project file is a main one? (to get filelist from) And if your projects all have different lists of files? This would need merging etc. etc.

For now `cocos new` only copies files from one place to another. Frankly, Cocos2d-x have much more serious problems to solve, so I don't think this feature will ever be implemented.

However, you could customize project files/folders to your needs to make process of adding files more or less convenient and sometimes even automatic. Here are some clues:

- It is easy to change Android and Linux `Makefile`s so they will pick up all the source files from a specified folder. Just use wildcards. Resource files are picked up by default.
- For Visual Studio solutions (Win32, Win8, WinPhone) you could enable "Show all files" to see all files that either added or not. Unfortunately you can only see files down in the folder tree relative to project folder. To see `Classes` folder, make a symlink (`link /j`) of a `Classes` folder near `.vcxproj` file. You'd better don't copy/move project folder after it. And don't forget to add this linked folder to ignore list of your versioning system, or you will end up with duplicated files. Resource files are picked up by default for Windows projects.
- I am not aware of any solution for XCode project, so you basically stuck with manual source file addition. Which is most annoying among all platforms. However it can pick up resource folders with all files.

Anyway, I would be glad if someone would proof me wrong and would write some kind of script to solve this problem (and also to change project name, company id, automatic versioning, etc.). I believe it could be done more or less reliably with, let's say Python and some regex magic. At least until project file formats will change.